# Android Studio Update stuck cleaning up?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just downloaded and installed Android Studio 0.8.  When I ran it, I received a notice that there was an update.  I immediately downloaded the patch and it auto-ran.  After patching, the dialog titled "Update" appears to be stuck with the following prompt:

> Updating Android Studio (build 135.1245622) to Android Studio
>   (build.135.1248636)
>
> (progress bar animation)
>
> Cleaning Up

If I click on the Cancel button, I get a new Yes/No dialog box saying:

> The patch has not been applied yet.
>
> Are you sure you want to abort the operation?

How can I fix this problem?

Running on Windows 8.1
JDK version 1.8.0_05

Comment: I have no real idea of what may be happening but providing some more info like OS Version, Java version and such may help those who do

Comment: @Machinarius Good idea, adding that now.

Comment: I'm getting this for the 0.82 upgrade, too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've also experienced this with the latest updates (0.8.1 - 0.8.4), both in Windows 7 and Windows 8.1, but there's actually nothing wrong.

The "Cleaning Up" part takes an *amazingly* long time (literally, several minutes), but it finishes OK. You just need to wait. :)

Very surprising for what would *seem* to be such a small update (at least judging from the downloaded file size).

Comment: 0.8.2 update cleanup took about 10 minutes today; W7, AMD Phenom II 3.4 GHz.

Comment: yay! I didn't botch my installation!

Comment: Yea you just have to be patient. I've no idea why it takes so long.

Comment: Indeed. For the record, I didn't have this problem with the 0.8.5 update. Maybe it was fixed?

Answer (score 7):

It took an hour for the "cleaning up..." step to finish on my Windows 8 machine. For whoever still has this problem, I don't know if it's a coincidence, but it finished 1 minute after I closed all my other open applications (e.g. browser).

Comment: Same here, I had to close Chrome by going to the task tray and doing it from there because it runs in the background.

Comment: Same here, finished immediately after closing Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while updating to version 0.8.2
The update froze at the 'cleaning up' screen. It was very late, so I let it run while I watched tv and fell asleep. Next morning I started my computer and the update screen was still there :O So I found this forum and did everything you guys said, but nothing seemed to work for me. I cancelled the update and got a Java IOException. It said that the update couldn't delete files and or folders inside the Temp folder of the LocalAppdata dir (C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Temp). I logged out and logged in again and started Android Studio. Everything ran fine and the update was succesfully applied.

So if someone experiences this too and the update freezes for longer than 1 hour, you can try to abort it, log out and log in again. And maybe it works again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is to do with this, but I could be wrong:

On some Windows systems, the launcher script does not find where Java is installed. If you encounter this problem, you need to set an environment variable indicating the correct location.
Select Start menu > Computer > System Properties > Advanced System Properties. Then open Advanced tab > Environment Variables and add a new system variable JAVA_HOME that points to your JDK folder, for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has occurred for me for the last few updates, including the update to 0.8.4.

I'm on Windows 8.1 pro 64 bit.

I kill the cleanup window after a few minutes using Task Manager. I restart Android Studio, everything works as usual, and I can see the new update version number in Help > About (0.8.4 in this case).

This is listed in the Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker - [Updater from 0.8.1 hung on Cleaning Up](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73365)

This issue is now fixed for me going from 0.8.4 to 0.8.5, as detailed at [Issue 73989: Patch updating Studio fails on Windows because it cannot delete files](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73989)

Note specifically that I attempted to delete all files in C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Temp\ manually.

I couldn't delete

"C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Temp\idea.updater.2226438342747264268.tmp\temp.4196595786233368387.tmp\lib\openapi.jar"

... until I restarted Windows.

So some mysterious lock on a file like that might be reproducing the problem for others.